# Is the bolas a one time use weapon?

Tags: a-dark-room

I have one bolas (taken from a city) but I do not want to use it as I think it may be a one-use weapon from looking up what it does on the internet in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, [bolas are consumed when used](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons#Bolas).**

Bolas will stun your enemy when used.

Answer (score 0):

It is one - use, but you will eventually be able to buy more.

Answer (score 0):

They can only be used once but you should buy more.